# Webkit rendering issue with fixed background and element

Tags: html, google-chrome, rendering, fixed

I'm having a weird rendering issue on Chrome Mac/android, when I set my backgrounds to be fixed, and I have a fixed element that the page scroll will cover by one of those background. I'm not seeing the artifacts in Safari, only on chrome.

```
html, body {width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
body {background:url(http://www.unsigneddesign.com/Seamless_background_textures/1200px/seamlesstexture14_1200.jpg) fixed;}
#logo {position:fixed; left:50%; top:50%; margin:-25px 0 0 -60px; background:url(http://www.seomofo.com/downloads/new-google-logo-knockoff.png) no-repeat; background-size:100% 100%; width:129px; height:50px;}
#content {width:100%; height:3000px; margin-top:100%; background:url(http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/textures/19.jpg) fixed; position:relative;}
#footer {height:100%;}

<div id="logo"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

It's hard to explain, I recommend to try it out directly:

http://jsfiddle.net/RKtH4/

I was curious to know if someone else is seeing the issue, and if there is a fix ?

Comment: i see the grey texture scroll over the google. im not sure what you are saying, your question is a bit vague. can you explain?

Comment: If you don't know what I am talking about, you are probably not experiencing this issue. On my version of Chrome, is it quite obvious. It's easier to see it when you scroll faster. I'm runing Version 33.0.1750.152 on OSX 10.9.2. Take a look at my screenshot http://oi59.tinypic.com/107oxgh.jpg

Comment: As I tried this morning on a different mac (not retina display), with the same os version and same chrome version, I am wondering if the fact I originally discover the issue on a retina display MBP but I can't reproduce on a non-retina display ...

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this same issue where there are two or more images that use `background-attachment:fixed`. It is only a Chrome issue on a Mac Retina display, and I reported it as a bug.

The redraw appears to be trying to put both images on top of each-other as Chrome doesn't know which one is more important to render so it renders both. Setting a z-index doesn't help nor does setting a translate3d. The only thing that helps is to hide one of the images until it is desired to be seen, then show it and hide the other. The problem with this is it doesn't allow for the desired effect.

Renderings are fine in Firefox and Safari on the retina display and also fine on non-Retina displays in Chrome.

Comment: One additional note in the issue was that position of the conflicting node was set to fixed as well as the background-attachment was fixed. I believe having these two values caused my particular issue. Once I changed the position of the node to absolute, the issue went away.